# How to debug a program with coroutines

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, c++-coroutine

I read that coroutines are stackless.

How to debug a program using coroutines ?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Heck, C++ on the whole can be stackless.

Comment: Coroutines uses stack in execution, but they store their state to heap before suspending.

Comment: Normally, debugging coroutines should be as easy as normal functions. But when I tried, I found out that only on Visual Studio the debugger can find local variables. With Clang/LLDB and GCC/GDB, it seems that local variables can't be displayed. I hope this will be fixed soon.

Comment: If your debugger breaks inside a coroutine, you will find the current frame has only one parameter, the `frame_ptr`. There are no local variables, no `this` pointer, no function parameters could be seen. Coroutines access their variables differently from normal functions. The variables are not on the stack, and everything is done through the `frame_ptr`